# Azure Packaging in Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-deployment, azure-packaging

I have an Azure cloud project stored in VSOnline. Is there a way to automatically package the cloud project and drop to a location in VSOnline itself? I have tried the AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml template which does not meet my requirement since it deploys the application to cloud service.

Comment: Doesn't the cloud project on Azure only contain binaries? If, that seems an odd request. What is it on Azure you want to add to VSOnline, and when?

Comment: I want VSOnline auto build to package my Azure project and copy the package to a drop location. Azure package contains two files cspkg and a cscfg file.